# When querying large data sets, prevent script timeout

Tags: php, mysql, timeout

I have the following code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable2 (col1, col2) 
                 VALUES ('".$row['val1']."', '".$row['val2']."')");
}
```

Understandably, the script times out at about 150,000 queries... outside of increasing the script memory what's the best way to prevent timeouts?

Comment: @GabrielGartz: could you give me a working example of how that would be implemented?

Comment: I like the RolandoMySQLDBA solution, but you also can echo something in your loop statement and flush it with http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not run it as a single query ???

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO mytable2 (col1,col2) SELECT val1,val2 FROM mytable";
$query = mysql_query($SQL);
```

## **ALTERNATIVE**

You could also throttle your INSERTs 200 at a time

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable"); 
$commit_count = 0;    
$commit_limit = 200;
$comma = "";
$SQL = "INSERT INTO mytable2 (col1, col2) VALUES ";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){ 
    $SQL .= $comma . "('".$row['val1']."','".$row['val2']."')";
    $comma = ",";
    $commit_count++;
    if ( $commit_count == $commit_limit )
    {
        mysql_query($SQL);
        $SQL = "INSERT INTO mytable2 (col1, col2) VALUES ";
        $commit_count = 0;    
        $comma = "";
    }
} 
if ( $commit_count > 0 ) { mysql_query($SQL); }
```

You can change the `$commit_limit` to whatever positive number that is reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

You should consider using an [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html) statement instead of running lot's of single inserts.